# Woocommerce products loop with product attribute filtering

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

As woocommerce shortcode, unfortunately, doesn't support filtering by product attributes. I'm trying to modify this simple products loop script to return just product based by url parameters (ex: `mysite.com/?location=paris`). As it's normally in product-archive page.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but Woocommerce shortcodes [**support product attributes filtering**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#content-product-attributes).

Comment: Filtring the product by attribute with change the url to look like: mysite.com/?filter_location=paris. and i'm trying to use this parameter to filter products in other pages. So the woocommerce shortcode filter with not solve my problem.

Comment: You can embed a shortcode in a custom shortcode and then get the needed filtering on it, like in the answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done embedding [products] Woocommerce shortcode in a custom shortcode that will get the product attribute query string to filter the displayed products.

To Woocommerce product attributes taxonomy start all by **"pa_"** + the attribute slug. So you will need to set your URL this way: `mysite.com/?pa_location=paris`.

So here it is a functional custom shortcode example that allow product attribute filtering:

```
function get_products_by_attribute( $atts ) {
    // Shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'columns' => '4', // Product ID
        'attribute' => '',
        'terms' => '',
        '$orderby' => 'title',
    ), $atts, 'products_attr' );

    $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if( $queryString ){
        parse_str($queryString, $results);

        foreach ( $results as $key => $values ) {
            if( substr( $key, 0, 3 ) === 'pa_' ) {
                $attribute = str_replace( 'pa_', '', $key );
                $terms     = $values;
                $filtering_attribute = "attribute='$attribute' terms='$terms'";
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    $filter = isset($filtering_attribute) ? $filtering_attribute : '';
    $cols   = $atts['columns'];
    $ordby  = $atts['$orderby'];

    return do_shortcode("[products columns='$cols' $filter orderby='$ordby']");
}
add_shortcode('products_attr', 'get_products_by_attribute');
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE Examples:**

Your Url will be like: `mysite.com/?pa_location=paris`

1) In the wordpress text editor of a page or a post:

```
 [products_attr columns='3' orderby='rand']
```

2) In the html code of a php file:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[products_attr columns='3' orderby='rand']"); ?>
```

3) Inserted in the php code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[products_attr columns='3' orderby='rand']");
```

---

You can customize it adding [any available arguments from Woocommerce shorcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6) to the code

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks you very much @LoicTheAztec.